# Stripe Payment Integration problem In Laravel . When I submit form its say given below

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
The stripe form here I use the post method

```
<form action="{{ route('paid') }}" method="POST">
                                          <script
                                          src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                                          data-key="pk_test_51Gx4RHGN82mlZ9FRpFQJX53WYhxxiNUDyANdIU7JTBOp2VE9UqCU7Me2YLu0pGdbhmFCfhBU670F9cTdzcKVH6s200EvaEy45p"
                                          data-amount="999"
                                          data-name="Stripe.com"
                                          data-description="Widget"
                                          data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
                                          data-locale="auto"
                                          data-zip-code="true">
                                      </script>
                                  </form>
```

And the route is given below

```
Route::post('/paid', 'PublicController@paid')->name('paid');
```

And controller

```
 public function paid(Request $request)
{

     dd($request->all());
}
```

I use post method but it always says
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

how can I solve it? I am so tired to solve this. please help me, anyone
Thanks

Comment: unfortunately @csrf missing   here

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has an inbuilt function called Laravel Cashier, you should use this instead of coding it through your method as it will be far simpler:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/billing

If you want to fast track it even further you can use this which will give you some initial dashboards to work with:

https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-cashier-examples

I hope that helps